# What is the distribution of $Z=E[X|Y]$ conditional on $X$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $F$ be a CDF in $\mathbb R^2$ and $X,Y$ random variables such that $(X,Y)\sim F$. Let $Z=E[X|Y]$. What is the distribution of $Z$ conditional on $X$, i.e $P(Z \in \cdot | X=x)$ ? One could say it is just a Dirac, since "if $X=x$, then $Z=E[x|Y]=E[x]=x$". Now this is not rigorous at all and I definitely feel is wrong. This is the same as saying that the distribution of $Z$ conditional on $X$ is the distribution of $E[X|Y,X]=E[X]$, which is wrong, right? Another way I could convince myself that it is wrong is that $Z$ is a mesurable function of $Y$, not $X$, hence knowing values of $X$ should not influence the outcome of $Z$.

I feel this question should be trivial, but I am not seeing it.

Now what happens if we ask a very similar question: what is the distribution of $Z$ given $X=x$ and $Y=y$? There is nothing random in $Z$ anymore because we know $Y$. So this time it should be a Dirac, i.e $E[X | Y=y]$, correct? Now what role would the conditioning on $X$ play in this scenario?

Comment: Indeed, $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)$ itself is a function of $Y$.  Which is to say if we let $g(y):=\mathsf E(X\mid Y=y)$, then we have $Z=g(Y)$.  This *will* be dependent on $X$ in so much that $X,Y$ have a *joint distribution*; with cumulative distribution function $F$.

Comment: It really does not look like there will be a trivial answer.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you. What about the second question?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$ be the conditional probability density function of $Y$ at $y$ given $X=x$ (assuming the density exists). Let $G_x(z)$ be the CDF of $Z$ conditioned on $X=x$, then
$$
G_x(z) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{Y|X=x}(y)\, \mathbf{1}_{\langle X|Y=y \rangle<z}(y)\, dy,
$$
where $\mathbf{1}_{\langle X|Y=y \rangle<z}(y)$ is the indicator function of $\langle X|Y=y \rangle<z$.

Only in the simple case where the value $y$ at which $E(X|Y=y)=z$ is a monotonic function of $z$ do we get a simpler expression for $G_x(z)$. In this case, let us call this function $y^*(z)$ (and w.l.o.g., assume $y^*$ is an increasing function of $z$). Then we have
$$
G_x(z) =\int_{-\infty}^{y^*(z)} f_{Y|X=x}(y)\, dy = F_{Y|X=x}(y^*(z)),
$$
where $F_{Y|X=x}$ is the conditional CDF of $Y$ given $X=x$.

Comment: Even if we admit that densities exist, what you defined as $G$ is not the conditional CDF of $Z$.

Comment: @W.Volante I admit, I took the liberty of assuming the PDFs exist, but why is $G$ not the conditional CDF of $Z$? The probability of $Z<z$ is the probability of $\langle X|Y\rangle < z$ which is $\int f_Y(y)\mathbf{1}_{\langle X|Y=y\rangle < z}(y) dy$, you just need to condition it on $X=x$.